# How to resolve rollup build error when using emotion: 'default' is not exported by @emotion\memoize\dist\memoize.cjs.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rollupjs, emotion

I'm trying to build a standardized react button component for our enterprise library. I want to be able to use @emotion/styled to generate the styled react component. We are using rollup as our package builder, which is transpiling from typescript to esm and commonjs. When I run the build, I'm getting the following error:
`Error: 'default' is not exported by node_modules\@emotion\memoize\dist\memoize.cjs.js
node_modules\@emotion\is-prop-valid\dist\is-prop-valid.esm.js (1:7)
1: import memoize from '@emotion/memoize';`

I'm still learning the ins and outs of building with rollup and typescript, so I can't tell if I'm just doing something wrong, or if there's an actual issue with the @emotion libraries.

I've tried setting :

```
commonjs({
    include: ['/node_modules/**', '../../../node_modules/**'],
    namedExports: {
        'node_modules/@emotion/memoize/dist/memoize.cjs.js': ['memoize']
    }
})
```

and

```
commonjs({
    include: ['/node_modules/**', '../../../node_modules/**'],
    namedExports: {
        'node_modules/@emotion/memoize/dist/memoize.cjs.js': ['default']
    }
})
```

But neither work.
I've tried installing different versions of @emotions, from 10.0.0 to 10.0.10, and it happens with all versions.
I've also tried installing @emotion/memoize directly, but it also didn't work.

Here are my build settings and code:

custom-button.tsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import CustomButtonProps from './custom-button-props';
import styled, { StyledComponent } from '@emotion/styled';
import { StyleConstants } from '@enterprise-api/constants';

export class CustomButton extends React.PureComponent<CustomButtonProps> {
    public constructor(props: CustomButtonProps) {
        super(props);
    }

    private DefaultButton: StyledComponent<any, any, any> = styled.button`
        height: 2rem;
        padding-left: 0.75rem;
        padding-right: 0.75rem;
        ${StyleConstants.defaultButton}
    `;

    public render(): React.ReactNode {
        if (this.props.style) {
            return (
                <button style={this.props.style} onClick={this.props.onClick}>
                    {this.props.text}
                </button>
            );
        }
        return <this.DefaultButton onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.text}</this.DefaultButton>;
    }
}

export default CustomButton;
```

custom-button-props.tsx

```js
import { MouseEvent, KeyboardEvent, CSSProperties } from 'react';

export interface CustomButtonProps {
    text: string;
    onClick: (event: MouseEvent | KeyboardEvent) => void;
    style?: CSSProperties;
}

export default CustomButtonProps;
```

rollup.config.js

```
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import pkg from './package.json';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';

export default {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: [
        {
            file: pkg.main,
            format: 'cjs',
            exports: 'named'
        },
        {
            file: pkg.module,
            format: 'es',
            compact: true
        }
    ],
    external: [...Object.keys(pkg.peerDependencies || {})],

    plugins: [
        typescript({
            typescript: require('typescript')
        }),
        resolve(),
        commonjs({
            include: ['/node_modules/**', '../../../node_modules/**']
        })
    ]
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./lib/", // path to output directory
        "sourceMap": false, // allow sourcemap support
        "strictNullChecks": true, // enable strict null checks as a best practice
        "module": "es6", // specify module code generation
        "jsx": "react", // use typescript to transpile jsx to js
        "target": "es5", // specify ECMAScript target version
        "allowJs": false, // allow a partial TypeScript and JavaScript codebase
        "strict": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true
    },
    "include": ["src"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/__tests__/*"]
}
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "@custom-component/button",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "lib/index.js",
    "types": "lib/index.d.ts",
    "module": "lib/index.esm.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "jest --config jestconfig.json --coverage",
        "document": "typedoc --out documentation --hideGenerator --includeDeclarations --exclude \"**/node_modules/**\" src/",
        "compile": "rollup -c",
        "audit": "yarn audit --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org --json > audit-results.json",
        "build": "yarn run clean && yarn run document && yarn run compile",
        "clean": "shx rm -rf lib documentation",
        "prepublishOnly": "yarn run build && yarn version --patch"
    },
    "files": [
        "lib/**/*"
    ],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@emotion/core": "^10.0.0",
        "@emotion/styled": "^10.0.0",
        "@types/jest": "^24.0.3",
        "@types/react": "^16.8.8",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^1.1.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^1.1.0",
        "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
        "eslint": "^5.12.0",
        "jest": "^24.5.0",
        "react": "^16.8.5",
        "rollup": "^1.7.2",
        "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^9.2.0",
        "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^4.0.0",
        "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.20.1",
        "shx": "^0.3.2",
        "ts-jest": "^24.0.0",
        "typedoc": "^0.14.2",
        "typescript": "^3.2.4"
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
        "@types/react": "^16.8.8",
        "react": "^16.8.5"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@emotion/core": "^10.0.0",
        "@emotion/styled": "^10.0.0",
        "@enterprise-api/constants": "^0.0.8-beta"
    }
}
```

I should be able to build this component without any issue, but instead I get the error above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try below way, hopefully it will work

```
commonjs({
  include: 'node_modules/**',
  namedExports: {
    'node_modules/@emotion/memoize/dist/memoize.cjs.js': ['memoize']
  }
}),
```

Comment: Sorry, I saw that I had pasted the text in without switching the \ to / in what i had tried. That is actually one of the things I tried, but no luck. Thanks though.

Comment: Can you please clean ur devDependencies, i can see duplicate dependency there for @emotion/core, emotion/styled. Also can you please install emotion as dependency and try rebuilding

Comment: Links might help : https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Troubleshooting#name-is-not-exported-by-module
https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs/issues/206

Comment: Following the the thread in that issue helped me to get the package to build by setting `include: [/node_modules/]` as a regex. However, when I try to use the component, I'm now receiving an error stating memoize_cjs is not a function in the built package.

Comment: There is an open bug for this at rollup, not resolved yet. you'll have to do the imports the ugly way for now. https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/3011#issuecomment-516947459

Comment: Hey I wasn't having the exact problem as you but when I implemented EmotionJS into my component library I was having issues. I did what Steve mentioned and it fixed my issue.

I was using commonjs; I changed `commonjs({ include: ['node_modules/**'], ...)}` to `commonjs({ include: [/node/modules/], ...)}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but this fixed the same issue you had. I thought it was the MUI v5 libraries that I imported so then I removed them to isolate the issue. Then I encounter the issue below:

[Rollup Error: 'default' is not exported by node_modules/react/index.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61237208/rollup-error-default-is-not-exported-by-node-modules-react-index-js)

And using the replace() plugin fixed all those issues. I'm encountering new issues but at least it let me get past this.

Comment: Actually it turns out, if you look at the code, you will see something similar to:

'use strict';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  module.exports = require("./unitless.cjs.prod.js");
} else {
  module.exports = require("./unitless.cjs.dev.js");
}

Thus the replace() plugin fix works.