# Rollup Error: 'default' is not exported by node_modules/react/index.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, commonjs, rollupjs

I have a project where I use webpack and want to switch to rollup.js but I have trouble regarding the plugin @rollup/plugin-commonjs.

### My rollup.conf.js

```js
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import nodePolyfills from 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills';

const config = {
    input: 'site/templates/scripts/master.js',
    output: [
        {
            file: 'site/templates/scripts/master.min.js',
            format: 'cjs'
        }
    ],
    plugins: [
        nodePolyfills(),
        resolve({
            browser: true
        }),
        commonjs({
            include: /node_modules/,
            namedExports: {
                'react': ["useState", "useEffect"],
                '@apollo/client': ['ApolloProvider', 'ApolloClient', 'HttpLink', 'InMemoryCache', 'useQuery', 'gql'],
                'styled-components': [ 'styled', 'css', 'ThemeProvider' ]
            }
        }),
        babel({
            babelrc: true,
            exclude: 'node_modules/**'
        }),
        terser()
    ]
};

export default config;
```

### The Error I'm getting and don't know to solve

```sh
site/templates/scripts/master.js → site/templates/scripts/master.min.js...
[!] Error: 'default' is not exported by node_modules/react/index.js, imported by site/templates/scripts/src/BgProductRecommendations/FredhopperProduct.js
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#error-name-is-not-exported-by-module
site/templates/scripts/src/BgProductRecommendations/FredhopperProduct.js (3:7)
1: 'use strict';
2: 
3: import React from "react";
          ^
4: 
5: const FredhopperProduct = ({
Error: 'default' is not exported by node_modules/react/index.js, imported by site/templates/scripts/src/BgProductRecommendations/FredhopperProduct.js
    at error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:10152:30)
    at Module.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:14487:16)
    at handleMissingExport (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:14388:28)
    at Module.traceVariable (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:14871:24)
    at ModuleScope.findVariable (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:13448:39)
    at FunctionScope.findVariable (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:8661:38)
    at ChildScope.findVariable (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:8661:38)
    at MemberExpression.bind (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:11285:49)
    at CallExpression$1.bind (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:8746:23)
    at CallExpression$1.bind (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:11473:15)
```

The https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#error-name-is-not-exported-by-module page does not really help, since I have all named exports which I use in my config.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Finally I found what was wrong. I needed the `@rollup/plugin-replace`plugin to replace `process.env.NODE_ENV`

### Here's the working code

It needed also some more namedExports.

```
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import nodePolyfills from 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';

import React from 'react';
import ReactIs from 'react-is';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const config = {
    input: 'site/templates/scripts/master.js',
    output: [
        {
            file: 'site/templates/scripts/master.min.js',
            format: 'cjs'
        }
    ],
    plugins: [
        replace({
            "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("development")
        }),
        nodePolyfills(),
        resolve({
            browser: true
        }),
        commonjs({
            include: /node_modules/,
            namedExports: {
                'react-is': Object.keys(ReactIs),
                'react': Object.keys(React),
                'react-dom': Object.keys(ReactDOM),
                '@apollo/client': ['ApolloProvider', 'ApolloClient', 'HttpLink', 'InMemoryCache', 'useQuery', 'gql'],
                'styled-components': [ 'styled', 'css', 'ThemeProvider' ]
            }
        }),
        babel({
            babelrc: true,
            exclude: 'node_modules/**'
        }),
        terser()
    ]
};

export default config;
```

Comment: Hmm. I must be doing something wrong because I have all of the identified changes and still get that error.

Comment: @MikeS. Check your `packages.json` file and add `react` at least for `peerDependencies` not only in `devDependencies`. This may help.

Comment: You're a life-saver--this combination of plugins fixed my issue!

Answer (score 8):

The solution for this problem is to update commonjs option to make it as below

```
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
// rollup.config.js
export default {
  input: 'src/app.ts',
  output: [
    {
...
    commonjs({
      include: /node_modules/,
      requireReturnsDefault: 'auto', // <---- this solves default issue
    }),
```

documentation link:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-commonjs
search for `requireReturnsDefault`

Comment: For me the issue was that I needed it to work for external packages as well (e.g. `lodash`), so I had to switch to `requireReturnsDefault: 'esmExternals'`. But your answer got me to that setting, so thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As of the latest `@rollup/plugin-commonjs` version, namedExports are handled by default.

Also try using this rollup babel config, requires the `@babel/preset-react` module to be installed

```js
     babel({
        exclude: "node_modules/**",
        presets: ["@babel/preset-react"],
        babelHelpers: "bundled",
      }),
```

And since the date of the issue most rollup plugins have been namespaced so try to reinstall `@rollup/plugin-babel`